# Use a spatial lag model to predict (in R)

Tags: regression

I have two polygon datasets, one for year 2010 and another for year 2015, each containing multiple features with a number of different variables.

I used a spatial lag model to predict the dependent variables (urban density) in the 2010 dataset. This was done in R.

For the 2015 data I only have explanatory variables, no urban density, and would like to predict  urban density for 2015 using the results/coefficients from the 2010 spatial lag model.

I can do this with a linear regression model in R by using the predict function, see [link](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/simple-linear-regression/estimated-simple-regression-equation). But I can't get that to work on spatial data, wont work because it doesn't take space in to consideration.

Comment: Could you add more about the spatial lag model you used? What variables went into the 2010 model, especially what spatial ones? What spatial variables specifically are missing from the 2015 data that you are trying to calculate in R?